# ¿Cómo modificar una imagen?

Tags: c#

Quiero saber si en modo consola C#, puedo encontrar archivos *.bmp, *.jpg, etc, solo de imágenes y que las modifique, que se muestre tal como indica aquí.
[img][https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/1692623[/img]](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/1692623%5B/img%5D)
[Ver imagen](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/1692623).

Nota:
La imagen amarilla de arriba se tener el ascii en tramas de bytes almacenado en C#, por ejemplo, abres un archivo de imagen con un editor hexadecimal, copias el contenido en Byte[] y lo pones en un archivo llamado imagenAmarilla.cs por poner un ejemplo.

Su contenido es este:

```
byte[] rawData = {
    0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE0, 0x00, 0x10, 0x4A, 0x46, 0x49, 0x46, 0x00, 0x01,
    0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0x60
};
```

En realidad es mucho más grande, este es un fragmento para de la imagen amarilla para que se entienda aquí en el foro y que quepa.

En resumen, que encuentre cada foto justo en el escritorio llamado jpg, png, bmp, etc... y que se modifique precisamente a la imagen de arriba.

Habrá cada variable tipo byte[], uno para jpeg, otro para bmp, otro para png, los que quieras. El programa detecta cada archivo y se modifica así en amarillo del ejemplo arriba. Así se podrá abrir la foto y se mostrará modificado.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

claro que puedes encontrar archivos de la extension que quieras, par hacerlo , puedes usar este codigo

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "*.jpg");
```

Podes cambiar la extension a la que quieras

Comment: Ahora a descubrir como se añade el código byte[] rawData = { indicado arriba, en cualquier imagen y guardarlo.